Flutterflow and Supabase, send ID instead of name
I'm using Flutterflow with supabase. I have a tableA that needs to receive the ID of tableB, but in the flutterflow search field the field used is "name" and not ID. How do I make my query for the name field in flutterflow send the ID?
